# Add Location as add_header inside location block

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

How to do we add Location inside add_header inside nginx location block for Response headers
So the Location inside response header looks like this. [image: Please see the last paramter]

The value of location header is same as the browser VIP

Answer (score 0):

Location header is relevant only with 3xx redirects. Using this header you're telling the client to what location it should redirect (how should URL change).

When configuring redirect by `rewrite` or `return` directives Nginx will automatically start including `Location` header in responses.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-nginx

If you want to explicitly set the location header to any response you could one of these (second one in case you're using some non-standard port):

`add_header Location $scheme://$host;`

`add_header Location $scheme://$host:$port;`

```
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        add_header Location $scheme://$host;
    }
```

Comment: I just edited above answer and added `;` sign at the end.. I tested this solution with docker container just now and it works fine:

```
curl -s -v http://localhost:8080
...
< Location: http://localhost

Comment: ; sign at the end even i had included but didnt work for me.Can you please ping me the entire nginx config line which worked for you

Comment: I tried with proxy_redirect as well.Actually may be in my setup its not letting me to redirect to internet F5

Comment: please provide full nginx config